# extension $ is not defined manifest v3

Tags: javascript, extension

popup.html

```
<script src="script.js"/>
```

script.js

```
var jsURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("jquery/jquery.min.js");

var jq = document.createElement('script');

jq.src = jsURL;

document.head.prepend(jq);


window.onload = function(){
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
       $.noConflict(true);
       $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    }, 5000);
}
```

manifest v3

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["jquery/jquery.min.js", "css/style.css" ],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "extension_ids": []
    }],
```

Ошибка
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Как инъекцировать jquery ?

Comment: вроде все верно делаете, возможно onload надо на элемент вешать. возможно, путь не может определиться (ошибок в консоли нет?). можно попробовать разные [варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery) динамического подключения jquery. динамическое подключение с cdn тоже не работает? (чтоб исключить проблему с getUrl)

Comment: Пробовал выше onload сделать, в head добавляет больше 1 тега script, не знаю почему, ошибка та-же, пробовал и googleapis внешний добавлять, но в  документации прочитал, что в 3 версии нельзя добавлять скрипты с внешний источников, но я попробовал, ошибка та-же.... Когда пробовал добавить внешний источник, в манифесте добавил  "content_security_policy": { "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://ajax.googleapis.com;" },